# Combine png-images to video with alpha channel in python

Tags: python, video, opencv

My Intention was:
- Extract all frames from video
- Apply background removal to each frame
- Merge all frames together as a video with transparency

Problem:
- The resulting video doesn't have the desired transparency where the background used to be
My code for the Merging-Part

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = r"C:\Users\youre\Documents\machine_learning\bg-rm\output"
video_name = r'C:\Users\youre\Documents\machine_learning\bg-rm\test.avi'
images =  # list of all frames
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), 30, (width, height))
for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

My question:
- What do I have to do in order to have my transparency over the background in the resulting video, because my code just gives me a black background. More specific: How do I merge the png-frames together with an alpha channel?

Comment: to read an image with alpha channel in opencv, you have to use the right imread flag. Afterwards you have to split rgb and alpha and use any blending technique you like to implement yourself, to merge both images with information from the alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

`MJPG` video format does not support alpha channel.
This is just a sequence of `JPEG` image and `JPEG` format does not support transparency.
You should choose a codec that support it. But I'm not sure one is available through OpenCV and this depends on your platform.

Instead you can save each image as PNG (with alpha channel) and merge them with a third party tool like FFMPEG.
HAP is the only free and open source video format that I know that support alpha channel but I don't know them all.